# Select a string that is contained inside a string from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I need to do an update based on whether a string from a column on table1 is inside another column on table2

**table1**

```
id     fruit     updateablefield
```

**table2**

```
id     fruitbowl updateablefield
```

**Example data**

**table1**

```
1 | apple

2 | orange

3 | mango

4 | grape
```

**table2**

```
1 | mango, pear,banana | false

2 |  grape, orange     | true
```

My update trigger query simplified is set as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build.onholdview_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN               
if new.updateablefield = true then  update table1 set updateablefield = true 
   where '%' || a.fruit || '%' like new.fruitbowls;                                                                                      
end if;

 RETURN NEW;                                                                    
END;
        

$function$
;
```

However this does not work. As you can see, the fruitbowls column is string aggregated using a comma. I also tried where block in fruitbowls, but it did not allow me to use the in this way. `UNNEST` also wasn't allowed. How to make an equality statement between the fruit and the fruitbowl

Comment: Fix table2 so it is not storing multiple values in a string.  At the very least, change the column to an array.  But it is better to have one value per row.

Comment: Add the trigger and trigger function definition, also it is not clear when you want to update what through this trigger

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't do that because table2 is an aggregation of table1. If I do that then table2 becomes table1 and users simply wont be able to go through thousands of rows

Comment: @AkhileshMishra added

Comment: you are calling this trigger function on which event ? before/after insert/update?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra as table2 is actually a view, this is instead of update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION onholdview_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN               
if new.updateablefield = true then  
 update table1 set updateablefield = true 
   where fruit = any(regexp_split_to_array(new.fruitbowls,',')) ;                                                                                      
end if;

 RETURN NEW;                                                                    
END;
        

$function$
;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9fd636f8304ece692a634e432c083eed)

Comment: Thanks dude! Realized I had to put (new.fruitbowls,', ') with a space between the single quotes because I've aggregated them with a space